# Sklearn fit vs predict, order of columns matters?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Say `X1` and `X2` are 2 pandas dataframes with the same columns, but possibly in different order. Assume model is some sort of `sklearn` model, like LassoCV. Say I do `model.fit(X1, y)`, and then `model.predict(X2)`. Is the fact that the columns are in different order a problem, or does model save weights my name of column?

Also, same question, but what if `X1` and `X2` and numpy arrays?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, I believe it will matter, as `sklearn` will convert the `pandas` DataFrame to an array of values (essentially calling `X1.values`), and not pay attention to the column names. However, it's an easy fix. Just use:

```
X2 = X2[X1.columns]
```

And it will re-order `X2`'s columns to the same order as `X1`

The same is true of `numpy` arrays, of course, because it will fit the model on the columns as they are in `X1`, so when you predict on `X2`, it will just predict based on the order of the columns in `X1`

**Example**:

Take these 2 dataframes:

```
>>> X1
   a  b
0  1  5
1  2  6
2  3  7

>>> X2
   b  a
0  5  3
1  4  2
2  6  1
```

The model is fit on `X1.values`:

```
array([[1, 5],
       [2, 6],
       [3, 7]])
```

And you predict on `X2.values`:

```
>>> X2.values
array([[5, 3],
       [4, 2],
       [6, 1]])
```

There is no way for the model to know that the columns are switched. So switch them manually:

```
X2 = X2[X1.columns]

>>> X2
   a  b
0  3  5
1  2  4
2  1  6
```

Comment: saved me from going bezerk :D

Comment: One week of struggle, and this finally helped!